# How to set the font color of quantity objects (Version 11.3 vs version 12)?

Tags: graphics, version-11.3, version-12

```
TD = 8 + 12 + 12 + 12 + 33 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   15/2 + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2;
CM = 15/2 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   24 + (3 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2 + (24 + 3/4) + 
   9/2;
TP = 2*90;

countsDim1 = {CM, TD, TP}/(TD + TP + CM)

n = 384 + 179;
labels = Placed[
   Row /@ Thread[{"" <> ToString@# <> 
         " H" & /@ {N[(n countsDim1[[1]]), 5], 
        N[(n countsDim1[[2]]), 5], Round@N[(n countsDim1)[[3]]]}}], 
   "RadialOuter"];
legend = Placed[
   SwatchLegend[Automatic, 
    Row /@ Thread[{{"CM ", "TD ", "TP "}, 
       Row[{"(", #, , ")"}] & /@ 
        Quantity[Round[100 countsDim1], "Percent"]}], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
       FontColor -> Black, FontWeight -> Bold}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 26], {After, Bottom}, Framed];

type = Framed[
  PieChart[countsDim1, ChartLabels -> labels, ChartLegends -> legend, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
     FontColor -> White, FontWeight -> Bold}, PlotTheme -> "Business",
    ImageSize -> Medium], Background -> LightGreen]
```

In Mathematica 11.3 above code would produce a Pie Chart with the percentage of the `Legend` black. In Mathematica 12, I get the text of the percentage with gray color.

[image: Version 12]

Below the same figure with Mathematica 11.3 (albeit without the bold text of the `LegendLabel`)

[image: Version 11.3]

What is different in Mathematica 12?

How can I get the percentage in black color (and bold)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be fully in control of the styling, I would suggest converting the quantity to a number.

I suggest replacing

```
Row[{"(", #, , ")"}]
```

with

```
Row[{"(", QuantityMagnitude[#], "%)"}]
```

Comment: Or eliminate `Quantity`: `Row[{"(", #, , "%)"}] & /@ Round[100 countsDim1]`

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a bug to me:

In version 12.0, the typesetting of `Quantity` objects in `TraditionalForm` (which is used for legends in `Legended` expressions) breaks after typesetting a quantity with the  same unit in `StandardForm`. To see this, consider the following example: (use a fresh kernel)

```
TraditionalForm@Quantity[3.5, "Percent"]
Quantity[3.5, "Percent"]
TraditionalForm@Quantity[3.5, "Percent"]
TraditionalForm@Quantity[1, "Percent"]
```

[image]

As you can see, quantities are typeset differently in `TraditionalForm`, and the one for `TraditionalForm` changes after typesetting in `StandardForm` once. The case of `1` is handled differently for some reason and does not break.

In 11.3, the typesetting of the `TraditionalForm` variant does not break after typesetting the `StandardForm` variant. This is why your example works in 11.3: The style for `TraditionalForm` does not set the `FontColor`, while the `StandardForm` one does (see `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "QuantityPanel"}]`, which is only used for `StandardForm`). That this works seems like a lucky coincidence, so I would suggest to use the method from @C.E.'s answer anyway, even if this gets fixed.

#### Tracking down the issue

The issue is caused by a change to the caching used for quantity typesetting:

```
(* cache lookup in 11.3 typesetting code for Quantity *)
QuantityUnits`QuantityBox[
  Quantity[n_, unit_?QuantityUnits`Private`UnitDisplayCacheContainsQ], form:StandardForm]
] := 
  Quiet[QuantityUnits`Private`getUnitDisplayForm[unit, n, form], {Part::partw}]

(* cache lookup in 12.0 typesetting code for Quantity *)
QuantityUnits`QuantityBox[
  Quantity[n_, unit_?QuantityUnits`Private`UnitDisplayCacheContainsQ], form_:StandardForm]
] := 
  Quiet[QuantityUnits`Private`getUnitDisplayForm[unit, n, form], {Part::partw}]
```

Note the change from `form:StandardForm` to `form_:StandardForm` - this extends the caching from `StandardForm` to all forms. The reason I think this is a bug is that this is the only definition of `QuantityBox` that defaults `form` to anything (all the others require an explicit form to be given), which suggests someone "fixed" a typo.

The issue with the caching code is that it ignores `form` when performing the cache lookup. Writing to the cache still requires `StandardForm` (here, the `form:StandardForm` pattern is still present in 12.0). The code was already questionable in 11.3 (since the caching partially supports forms other than `StandardForm`), but this was not an issue since it was only ever called with `StandardForm`.

Comment: Should I change the title of the question since it is misleading?

Comment: Well, it describes the original issue you were having - you could change it to "How to set the font color of quantity objects" to make it a bit more descriptive. This answer was more intended as an explanation of what changed, rather than as a direct solution to your problem